# Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem with this code, tell me about SyntaxError but i don't see any error in this code and i can't get it to work properly when i fire onchange function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function checkSeLivre(){
            var ajaxRequest;  
            try{
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e){
                    try{
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                            try{
                                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            } catch (e){
                                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                                    return false;
                            }
                    }
            }
           ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4 && ajaxRequest.status === 200){
                        var res = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        var result = res["status"];
                        var erro = res.message;
                        var ok = res.message;
                        console.log(result);
                        if(result == 'success'){
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivOk').style.display = "block";
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivOk').innerHTML = ok;
                            document.getElementById("ajaxDivErro").style.display = "none";

                        }
                        else{
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivErro').style.display = "block";
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivErro').innerHTML = erro;
                            document.getElementById("ajaxDivOk").style.display = "none";
                        }   
            }};
            var iduser = <?php echo $userid; ?>;
            var dia = document.getElementById('dia').value;
            var sala = document.getElementById('sala').value;
            var inicio = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
            var fim = document.getElementById('fim').value;
            var data = document.getElementById('data').value;    
            var queryString = "?iduser=" + iduser + "&dia=" + dia + "&sala=" + sala + "&inicio=" + inicio + "&fim=" + fim + "&data=" + data;
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", "checkSalaLivre.php" + queryString, true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null); 
        }
</script>
```

JavaScript error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on line 37

Line 37 is

```
 var iduser = <?php echo $userid; ?>;
```

Whats wrong?

UPDATE

What is the difference betwwen that javascript and this one? This one works in another page but have different variables

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function checkSeLivre(){
            var ajaxRequest;  
            try{
                    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e){
                    try{
                            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                            try{
                                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            } catch (e){
                                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                                    return false;
                            }
                    }
            }
           ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(ajaxRequest.readyState === 4 && ajaxRequest.status === 200){
                        var res = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                        var result = res["status"];
                        var erro = res.message;
                        var ok = res.message;
                        console.log(result);
                        if(result === 'success'){
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivOk').style.display = "block";
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivOk').innerHTML = ok;
                            document.getElementById("ajaxDivErro").style.display = "none";

                        }
                        else{
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivErro').style.display = "block";
                            document.getElementById('ajaxDivErro').innerHTML = erro;
                            document.getElementById("ajaxDivOk").style.display = "none";
                        }   
            }};
            var iduser = <?php echo $userid; ?>;
            var sala = document.getElementById('sala').value;
            var equip = document.getElementById('equip').value;
            var inicio = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
            var fim = document.getElementById('fim').value;
            var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
            var queryString = "?iduser=" + iduser + "&sala=" + sala  +"&equip=" + equip + "&inicio=" + inicio + "&fim=" + fim + "&data=" + data;
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", "checkEquipLivre.php" + queryString, true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null); 
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code.

Comment: `var iduser = <?php echo $userid; ?>;`  is not valid JavaScript syntax

Comment: try: `var iduser = '<?php echo $userid; ?>';`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not running this through a PHP interpreter. The offending line contains PHP, and is no valid JS.